# How to implement a trait on `{integer}` type in Rust

Tags: rust

Is there a way to implement a trait for `{integer}` type (or all integer types). Because (as a minimal example):

```rust
pub trait X {
    fn y();
}

impl<T> X for T {
    fn y() {
        println!("called");
    }
}

fn main() {
    (32).y();
}
```

gives an error:

```text
error[E0689]: can't call method `y` on ambiguous numeric type `{integer}`
  --> src/main.rs:12:10
   |
12 |     (32).y();
   |          ^
   |
help: you must specify a concrete type for this numeric value, like `i32`
   |
12 |     (32_i32).y();
   |      ~~~~~~

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0689`.
```

Is there a way to implement trait `X` for any integer type so that it can be used on any integer (even the ambiguous `{integer}` type)? Because if the implementation for all integer types, is the same why care about the exact type?

Comment: No, `{integer}` is deep magic in Rust and a very special case. It's not a real type and is only used as an intermediate in type inference.

Comment: [num_traits](https://docs.rs/num-traits/latest/num_traits/) can help consider many numeric types as a whole.

Comment: "Because if the implementation for all integer types, is the same why care about the exact type?" because the compiler cannot conclude it's the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to bound type `T` by `num_traits::PrimInt` like this:

```rust
use num_traits::PrimInt;

trait Trait {
    fn y(self) -> Self;
}

impl<T: PrimInt> Trait for T {
    fn y(self) -> Self {
        println!("called");
        return self;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = 32;
    println!("{}", x.y());
}
```

Comment: And I can use `num_traits::Float` for the `{float}` type?

Comment: @MarcellPerger, Yes.